# Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64

Tags: android, jdbc, android-room

I am using Android Studio [Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1]

```
My room library version is [2.3.0]
Used Gradle version [7.0.1]
Also added kapt 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.1'


Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and     os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64 at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:333) at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:64) at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier.<clinit>(DatabaseVerifier.kt:71)
```

**How to solve this error?**

**SOLUTION**
Use Room Version: 2.4.0-alpha03 or later.

Comment: Presumably, you need to get rid of `kapt 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.1'`. It is not an annotation processor and Room does not use that library.

Comment: I have removed that line and tried but still error.

Comment: Same question basically as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758513/getting-execution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin-when-trying-to-impleme?rq=1. The bug tracker for the issue is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174695268#comment9

Comment: Thanks, It woks for me.

Comment: anyone has any idea, why does difference in a computer chip has to do with how the library behaves.

Answer (score 189):

If you are using Apple M1 chip

One of the release notes they have mentioned by jetpack (Version 2.4.0-alpha03 )

- Fixed an issue with Room’s SQLite native library to support Apple’s M1 chips.

Change Version to 2.4.0-alpha03 or above

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-alpha03"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-alpha03"
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-alpha03'
```

Reference

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_2

Comment: This one works for me. So for anyone who get main error message about "A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution Room Database" but have to run --stacktrace to see real error "No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64".

Comment: `2.4.0-alpha05` also works.

Comment: This is weird but works. Yet dont you think being in Alpha would cause any problems in future or problems with live production apps. Thatt working with teams? @Abhimanyu

Comment: The same resolves the problem when the chip is Apple M1 Pro

Comment: Thank you. For today version 2.4.1 works well.

Comment: I still fails if I have both annotationProcessor and kapt. It will compile if I have only annotationProcessor, but it crashes because I'm using it with Kotlin

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. If you're doing the Google Codelab on SQL Databases in the Basics of Kotlin course, you need to go into build.gradle file in the Parks code, and change `def room_version` under dependencies to `'2.4.0-alpha03'`

Comment: for my project, doing the above reduces the error. and now  I am getting this error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @androidx.room.Database does not define an element autoMigrations()

Answer (score 74):

Update(26 October 2021) -
it seems that Room got fixed in the latest updates,
Therefore you may consider updating Room to the latest version :
---- 2.4.0-alpha03 ----     or above

For those who are facing this problem, you can simply add this line before the room-compiler as a workaround now:

`kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"`

If the mentioned workaround not working, I recommend using this workaround instead, adding it to the root build.gradle. This will force using the given dependency in the whole project:

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was facing the issue even after updating room to version 2.5.1. Adding this force resolution strategy did solve this issue finally!

Answer (score 22):

**Room [2.4.0-alpha04] fixed this issues.**

And remove kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. I don't really like the fact that my project randomly breaks like this without me having made any changes.  Feels very destabilizing.

Comment: I spend 1 hour to solve this issue! Thank you!

Comment: 2.4.2 is stable at this moment and I confirm this works on M1 Pro chipset.

Answer (score 22):

Here is what worked for me:

**Change `room` version to `2.3.0`** in app-level `build.gradle`

```
def room_version = "2.3.0" // for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

In project-level `build.gradle`, **add the following configuration in `allprojects`**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
    }

    // ADD THE FOLLOWING
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
        }
    }
}
```

**Clean & rebuild your project** :)

*Ref: [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174695268#comment10) on Google IssueTracker*

Comment: this is really help if anyone can't update room version from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0 alpha, thanks man :)) @Utsav Barnwal

Answer (score 16):

Room fixed this issues on [Version 2.4.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?hl=en#2.4.0-alpha03)

[Fixed an issue with Room’s SQLite native library to support Apple’s M1 chips.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174695268)

Update:
The room latest version is "2.4.2"

```
val roomVersion = "2.4.2"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

Answer (score 3):

We used JDK 11 and we had to move from default JDK to version >= 11.0.13. And that fixed build issues on M1.

Answer (score 1):

Macbook Air M1 -
I solved with this step:

Upgrade `kotlin at 1.6.0` version (search kotlin version in your project)
Upgrade `version.androidx.room` from `2.3.0` to `version.androidx.room=2.4.0` because of this:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_2

Only my case:
I added this lib

```
implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.0-alpha05")
```

If you use `@FlowPreview`, change this to `@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)`

Answer (score 1):

Macbook Pro - Chip M2 Pro 2023 model - macOS Sonoma - I solved with this info:

```
def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```