# resolve build failure in android studio - while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkActio

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-room, apple-m1, android-build

I have imported the project into android studio. I am the only one getting this error.

This is the headline of the error

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
```

Here is the stack trace:

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appmanager:kaptProdDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appmanager:kaptProdDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:992)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1335)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:82)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:57)
    at androidx.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:134)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:188)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:333)
 BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
189 actionable tasks: 177 executed, 12 up-to-date
     Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
```

***I have an update.
These error were thrown because of a bug in room library that has to do with apple M1 chip, I am using macbook pro M1 chip, I found related  questions asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758513/getting-execution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin-when-trying-to-impleme?rq=1) and after updating the room library version to 2.4.2, the above error is resolved. No I am getting this error.***

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @androidx.room.Database does not define an element autoMigrations()
at com.google.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors.getAnnotationElementAndValue(AnnotationMirrors.java:134)
at*

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @androidx.room.Database does not define an element autoMigrations()
    at com.google.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors.getAnnotationElementAndValue(AnnotationMirrors.java:134)
    at 
com.google.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors.getAnnotationValue(AnnotationMirrors.java:114)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacAnnotationBoxKt.box(JavacAnnotationBox.kt:71)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacElement.getAnnotations(JavacElement.kt:57)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.InternalXAnnotated.getAnnotations(InternalXAnnotated.kt:46)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.XAnnotated.getAnnotation(XAnnotated.kt:147)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:68)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:61)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:79)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:75)
    at androidx.room.processor.Context.collectLogs(Context.kt:149)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep.process(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:75)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep.process(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:42)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:122)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:188)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have an update. These error were thrown because of a bug in room library that has to do with apple M1 chip, I am using macbook pro M1 chip, I found related questions asked similar question and after updating the room library version to 2.4.2, the above error is resolved. No I am getting this error.

Thank you for this. I couldn't find the error in my app for 2 days. Turns out it was this...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32869529)